# in string, capitalize allcaps words and leave the rest alone

Tags: python

For example, having gone through this procedure the string:

```
Hello, WORLD, McGisty, you are my HERO THAT I am.
```

should return/be:

```
Hello, World, McGisty, you are my Hero That I am.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> x = 'Hello, WORLD, McGisty, you are my HERO THAT I am.'
>>> m = ' '.join(e.capitalize() if e.isupper() else e for e in x.split())
>>> m
'Hello, World, McGisty, you are my Hero That I am.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'Hello, WORLD, McGisty, you are my HERO THAT I am.'
>>> re.sub(r'[A-Z]+', lambda s: s.group().capitalize(), x)
'Hello, World, McGisty, you are my Hero That I am.'
```